# How can I trigger ng-move after a splice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I am using ng-animate and I have a list of entries iterated through using ng-repeat. When you make a selection on a particular entry, it disappears. I have defined `.ng-move, .ng-move-active, .ng-leave, .ng-leave-active` appropriately so that the `.leave` animation occurs when I perform a `.splice()` operation on my data, and the `.move` operation occurs when I reorder entries.

However, what I want is for when one of the entries is removed, the `.ng-leave` occurs on that entry while `.ng-move` slides them all up. I've found that `.splice()` doesn't trigger an `.ng-move` though, so I'm curious if there is a way to force that animation to happen after a `.splice()`?

Here is the html:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="entry in data" class="container card-drop card-shift">
    <card data="entry"></card>
</div>
```

Here are the css classes:

```
.card-drop.ng-leave {
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}

.card-drop.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0;
}

.card-shift.ng-move {
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.card-shift.ng-move.ng-move-active {
    transform: translateY(-284px);
}
```

And in the javascript the event I am concerned about is simply `$scope.data.splice(index, 1);`

EDIT: http://plnkr.co/edit/nz38XxPbV4Ycqdn3QYVP?p=preview

Above is the plunk for the issue I am referring to. Notice that when you click on an entry and it is spliced, the `.ng-leave` animation occurs but none of the `ng-move` animations do.

Comment: Can you share your code first ?

Comment: Please create a plunker where you reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that there was no easy way to do this. Ultimately I ended up manipulating DOM elements' CSS from within the directive to provide the sliding animation, then instantaneously shifted them to their original spot at the same time as the splice, resulting in the animation I was after, albeit in a hacky way.